# How to pass for loop php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple edit records. I used script below to compare the value of textbox1 in textbox 2. But the problem is, when I try to edit multiple records. The script function only on the first record. How I can pass the for loop in php to javascript?

For Loop

```
$id=$_POST['checkbox'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
```

This gets all records depends on number of checkbox that have been checked. And when I get all the value in for loop opens records depends on counter value. Just like this how I can pass this for loop functions to javascript?

```
<script>
$('#sbtBtn').live('click',function(){
    var textBox1=document.getElementById('pr_qty[]').value;
    var textBox2=document.getElementById('pr_total').value;


    if((+textBox2) > textBox1){
      alert('value is greater than quantity');  
        return false;
    }else{
         }
});
</script>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">    
<?php
$id=$_POST['checkbox'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
SELECT a.item_name, a.item_description, a.counter, b.counter, b.pr, b.total_quantity
FROM app a
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_request b
ON a.counter=b.counter
WHERE a.counter='$id[$i]'
    ");
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
      { ?>
      <div class="thumbnail">
    <div style="display:none;">
    <div class="control-label"></div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="counter[]" class="textbox" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['counter'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="control-label"  style='float:left;width:25%;margin-left:10%;text-align:left;margin-bottom:3px;'>Item</div>
    <div class="controls" style='float:left;width:65%;margin-bottom:3px;'>
        <input name="firstname[]" class="textbox" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['item_name'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
    </div>

    <div class="control-label"  style='float:left;width:25%;margin-left:10%;text-align:left;margin-bottom:3px;'>Description</div>
    <div class="controls" style='float:left;width:65%;margin-bottom:3px;'>
        <input name="lastname[]" class="textbox" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['item_description'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
    </div>

    <div class="control-label"  style='float:left;width:25%;margin-left:10%;text-align:left;margin-bottom:3px;'>PR Quantity</div>
    <div class="controls" style='float:left;width:65%;margin-bottom:3px;'>
        <input name="pr_qty[]" id="pr_qty[]"  class="textbox" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['total_quantity']; ?>" />
        <input id="pr_total" class="textbox" type="text" value="<?php $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, SUM(quantity) total_quantity FROM purchase_order WHERE counter='$id[$i]'");
        while($rows = $result2->fetch_assoc()){ echo $rows['total_quantity']; }
        ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="control-label"  style='float:left;width:25%;margin-left:10%;text-align:left;margin-bottom:3px;'>PR #</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="pr[]" class="textbox" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['pr'] ?>" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
      <?php 
      }
}
?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="sbtBtn" value="Update">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please give little bit more explanation on what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not give same id to multiple elements, you have to give unique id to your textboxes. In your function you getting textboxes byh Id, change it to class and also give separate classes to your textbox1 and 2. Otherwise your script will work on only first record.

**js change**

```
var textBox1=document.getElementsByClassName('tb1');
var textBox2=document.getElementsByClassName('tb2');

for(var i=0; i< textBox1.length; i++){
if((textBox2[i].value) > textBox1[i].value){
      alert('value is greater than quantity');  
        return false;
    }else{
         }
```

}

and **html change**

```
 <input name="pr_qty[]" id="pr_qty[]"  class="textbox tb1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['total_quantity']; ?>" />
            <input id="pr_total" class="textbox tb2" type="text" value="<?php $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, SUM(quantity) total_quantity FROM purchase_order WHERE counter='$id[$i]'");
            while($rows = $result2->fetch_assoc()){ echo $rows['total_quantity']; }
            ?>">
```

Comment: You can use jquery for js function

Comment: Even in the first record is not functioning the script

Comment: Can you remove plus Sign in if statement of for loop and try

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer, had forgot to put .value in if statement

Comment: btw do you wanna compare integer in if statement? so textboxes will contain only numbers?

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick event you can read input fields value like:

**EDIT:**

```
  var val1 = $("input[name='UR_ELE1_NAME']").val();
  var val2 = $("input[name='UR_ELE2_NAME']").val();
```

And you can compare like: `if(val1 > val2){ .....}`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sir akumar why on thumbnail?

Comment: Not in thumbnail, it is .form-horizontal. I have updated. plz check and let me know is it working?

Comment: I'm gonna change my whole script with this?

Comment: Right, just compare the value of textbox1 to textbox2. If textbox2 > textbox1 return false the functions.